# Only use AND statment when if is true in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement

I have updated an old system and I have a query problem.

To get to business this is the direct problem:

There are new records witch are associated with an id to other records. There are also old records which are not.

- Case1 : there is a INT id and when that is present the query has to use AND after an include.
- Case 2 : when the value of the INT id is 0 it has to do nothing

This is the part of the query where I need to make an variable AND statement:

```
LEFT JOIN table v ON v.producten_id = i.producten_id AND v.t5_id = i.t5_id AND i.id = v.inkoop_id
```

I never used IF stamens inside a query but i am looking for something like this:

```
LEFT JOIN table v ON v.producten_id = i.producten_id AND v.t5_id = i.t5_id if(v.inkoop_id > 0){AND i.id = v.inkoop_id}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LEFT JOIN table v
  ON v.producten_id = i.producten_id
    AND v.t5_id = i.t5_id
    AND (v.inkoop_id <= 0 OR i.id = v.inkoop_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this....

```
LEFT JOIN table v ON v.producten_id = i.producten_id
   AND v.t5_id = i.t5_id
   AND ((v.inkoop_id > 0 AND i.id = v.inkoop_id) OR (v.inkoop_id = 0))
```